# Why create-react-app required root account to create project

Tags: reactjs

I'm confused that why `create-react-app` required `root` account to create project? If I create a project with `create-react-app` without `root` aka `sudo`, it return following error message.

> Aborting installation.   yarnpkg add --exact react react-dom
>   react-scripts --cwd /Users/user/Documents/Projects/ReactJS/mytest has
>   failed.

If I create a project with `root`, it was working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`create-react-app` not require **root**, they need permissions to work with file system. So if you have some other account with this permission, feel free to use it.

Answer (score 1):

If you have installed `create-react-app` globally then only it requires `sudo` aka `root` permission because a command line tool needs your permission to make file or changes.

if you have not installed `create-react-app` globally then it might need the `sudo` aka `root` permission to make file or changes.